# Getting the coordinates of a marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of two markers on my google map to some textboxes. I have followed several guides that recommend using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
```

and

```
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
```

but, my textboxes don't get populated with anything.

Google map code(blurred out the key, but it works fine since i can access the map):

```
<div class="content">
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
<script>
function initMap() {
var cpe = {lat: -20.269401 , lng: 57.497840};
var pl = {lat: -20.187042 , lng: 57.498377};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 11,
center: cpe
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: cpe,
map:map,
draggable:true,
label: "P"


});

ar infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "Pickup Point"
});

marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: pl,
map:map,
draggable:true,
icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'

});


var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "Drop-Off Point"
});



marker2.addListener('mouseover', function() {
infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
});
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("fromlat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("fromlng").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("tolat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("tolng").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&callback=initMap">
</script>

</div>
```

Textboxes:

```
enter code here
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="fromlat" name="fromlat" placeholder="Pickup Latitutde(Auto)"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="fromlng" name="fromlng" placeholder="Pickup Longitude(Auto)"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="tolat" name="tolat" placeholder="Destination Latitude(Auto)"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="tolng" name="tolng" placeholder="Destination Longitude(Auto)"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the links to the guides, I'm a Codementor developer.

Answer (score 1):

you just only need to define your events function under initMap() function
Here are the script code.
Kindly review

```
<script>
var map;
function initMap() {
var cpe = {lat: -20.269401 , lng: 57.497840};
var pl = {lat: -20.187042 , lng: 57.498377};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 11,
center: cpe
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: cpe,
map:map,
draggable:true,
label: "P"


});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "Pickup Point"
});

marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: pl,
map:map,
draggable:true,
icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'

});


var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "Drop-Off Point"
});



marker2.addListener('mouseover', function() {
infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("fromlat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("fromlng").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker2, 'drag', function (event) {
document.getElementById("tolat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("tolng").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});


}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome @kvothe0153.